# Wave equation with piecewise initial condition

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve numerically the wave equation with the following initial and boundary conditions:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
  u[0, x] == 1 - Abs[x], (D[u[t, x], t] /. t -> 0 ) == 0, 
  u[t, 1] == 0, u[t, -1] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

This gives a warning

```
NDSolve::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 10000 allowed by the
MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x. >>
```

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Have you searched what the problem means ? I hear *Mathematica* has a decent documentation.

Comment: Yes, they suggest not to use the option "MaxPoints"... which I am not using.

Comment: When we take out the initial condition $\partial_t u (0,x)=0$ then the code works.

Answer (score 1):

```
uif = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
    u[0, x] == 1 - Abs[x], (D[u[t, x], t] /. t -> 0) == 0, 
    u[t, 1] == 0, u[t, -1] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}];
Plot3D[uif[t, x], {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The MethodOfLines always seemed me to have a low precision and to be awfully slow. Am I wrong? Is it the only way to solve time dependent problems?

Comment: What about icreasing accuracy/precision? (`NDSolveValue::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that ...`)

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, since the spatial discretization of FEM is second order accurate there is not much point in a higher order time integration. But I believe MOL uses a higher order. This example though does not seem to be slow. If you can provide an example where you think it should be faster let me know. Sometime the DAE initialization can take some time. And, yes, for FEM MOL is the only way to time integrate.

Comment: @mmal, it's always good to mention the input you used. I am not quite sure what you want to do.

Comment: @user21 Sorry, try your code with increased `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` say to 10.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, what you can do though is specify a different time integrator: `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", Method -> {"Adams"}, "SpatialDiscretization"->...} or "BDF" and I think that's documented somewhere. Probably [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html)

Comment: @mmal, hm, it's a bit odd that it can not initialize. Not sure. Even if it could I am not sure how useful if were as the FEM code is currently (10.2) only available in machine precision - but the time stepper should be able to do that.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, you could in principal also view this as a 2D problem: `uif = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
    u[0, x] == 1 - Abs[x], (D[u[t, x], t] /. t -> 0) == 0, 
    u[t, 1] == 0, u[t, -1] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement"}];
Plot3D[uif[t, x], {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}]` but in this case that's not a good solution.

Comment: @ user21 This is what I had in mind. Why is it not good?

Comment: I think you can answer this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95775/12 When is a sparse array with no values more useful than just a list of positions?

Comment: @user21, why the answer doesn't work for MA9 ? have you an idea?

Comment: @S.S., because it uses the finite element method, that was introduced in version 10.

Comment: @user21, okay thanks, it seems I have to update MA9 as soon as possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `NDSolve` spits out the warning probably because the exact solution is not smooth while `NDSolve` assumes it to be smooth so too many grid points are used for getting a accurate enough solution around the cusp, in other words, `NDSolve` is trying too hard by default. As showed by [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21), using FEM in v10 is a solution for this problem (because FEM is good at finding weak solution?), but if you're not yet in v10, you can just fix the space step size:

```
mol[n_, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

{sol4, solp} = 
   Quiet@NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
             u[0, x] == 1 - Abs[x], (D[u[t, x], t] /. t -> 0) == 0, 
             u[t, 1] == 0, u[t, -1] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}, 
           Method -> mol[##]] & @@@ {{33, 4}, {33}}
```

Without `Quiet`, the generation of `sol4` will be accompanied by some warnings complaining the solution isn't accurate enough, but it doesn't matter. Let's compare the solution with the analytic one:

```
half[t_, x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{(1 - Abs[x]), Abs@x > t && 0 <= t < 1}, {-(1 - Abs[x]), 
     2 - Abs@x < t && 1 <= t < 2}}, 1 - Abs@t];
(* The following is the analytic solution for one period, 
   I haven't yet figure out how to get the analytic solution with Mathematica*)        
one[t_, x_] = 
  PiecewiseExpand@Piecewise[{{half[t, x], 0 < t < 2}, {-half[t - 2, x], 2 < t < 4}}];

Animate[Plot[{sol4[t, x] - one[t, x], solp[t, x] - one[t, x]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> 0.02, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> Style["Error", 14]], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the error is quite small.