# What are pattern sparse arrays and how do I use them?

Tags: finite-element-method, sparse-arrays

I found a few references to something called a "pattern sparse array" that does not contain any values, only positions.  What is this data structure?  How and when do I use it?

---

From the documentation of [MSparseArray_getExplicitValues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/MSparseArray_getExplicitValues.html):

> For a pattern sparse array where only positions are stored and there are no values, the result will point to a null (0) `MTensor`.

Some graph objects also contain a sparse array like this.  The FullForm of e.g. `SeedRandom[42]; RandomGraph[{5, 6}]` contains

```
SparseArray[Automatic, {5, 5}, 0, {1, {{0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 12}, {{2}, {1}, {3}, {5}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {3}, {5}, {2}, {3}, {4}}}, Pattern}]
```

The ArrayRules of this array are

```
{{1, 2} -> _, {2, 1} -> _, {2, 3} -> _, {2, 5} -> _, {3, 2} -> _, {3, 
   4} -> _, {3, 5} -> _, {4, 3} -> _, {4, 5} -> _, {5, 2} -> _, {5, 
   3} -> _, {5, 4} -> _, {_, _} -> 0}
```

Finally, a regular sparse array has a method called `PatternArray`, which appears to create the equivalent sparse array with no values.

```
In[33]:= SparseArray[{0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3}] // InputForm
Out[33]//InputForm=
SparseArray[Automatic, {7}, 0, {1, {{0, 3}, {{3}, {4}, {7}}}, {1, 2, 3}}]

In[34]:= SparseArray[{0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3}]["PatternArray"] // InputForm
Out[34]//InputForm=
SparseArray[Automatic, {7}, 0, {1, {{0, 3}, {{3}, {4}, {7}}}, Pattern}]
```

Comment: [``NDSolve`StructuralIncidenceArray``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html#642842589)  -- I don't have *M* access right now, but can you create a `Graph` from a pattern sparse array?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, that is possible: `AdjacencyGraph@SparseArray[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}} -> _, {3, 3}]`.

Comment: My initial guess is that it is one of the principal applications (and that it is the application in the `NDSolve` link).

Comment: There is also an example use of `"PatternArray"` in the "Brusselator PDE" example of the LibraryLink tutorial [Numerical Examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/Numerical.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pattern sparse arrays are used, for example, in NDSolve to specify the structure of a Jacobian. This can save significant time while integrating a differential equation. In other words pattern sparse arrays are useful if one knows something about the structure of a sparse array but not (yet) about the values. There are some examples in the [FEM Programming tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html).

To extract a sparse array pattern one can use:

```
sa = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 1,{2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}];
spa = sa["PatternArray"];
spa["NonzeroValues"]
Pattern
```

And that's the reason for the documentation note you found. Since a sparse array can be a pattern array one needs to check that the value tensor actually has something in it.

Some algorithms like

```
SparseArray`ApproximateMinimumDegree[spa]
{3, 2, 1}

SparseArray`MinimumBandwidthOrdering[spa]
{{1, 1}, {{2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}}
```

can use a sparse pattern array. Or

```
FindShortestTour[AdjacencyGraph[Transpose[spa].spa]]
{3, {1, 3, 2, 1}}
```

In these cases the value of the sparse array is not relevant. So if you have a sparse array just use that if you need to construct a new one or have an operation that constructs a new one (like `Dot`) you can save the memory of the values and the time to compute the values if all you care about is the structure of the matrix

Comment: Is it a bug that this hangs? `SparseArray[{}, {10, 10}]["PatternArray"]`?

Comment: @Szabolcs, filed. Thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs, fixed in current sources.